# CakePHP HABTM relationship issue

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, relationships

I'm trying to create a social networking type of website where a user can send/receive a friend request. In our current system when a user sends a request half the required information is stored in the database then when a user accepts the rest of the information for the rest is inputted.

the relationships_users table  is id, partyone, partytwo, expirydate, active

the problem im having is once a user accepts a request and puts in an expiry date, its inserted in a new column - not in the column relating to that user

```
here is my add function

    if($this->request->is('post')){
    $this->Relationship->create(); 
    if ($this->Relationship->save($this->request->data)) 
    { 
        $this->Session->setFlash('The relationship has been saved');  

    }
    else { $this->Session->setFlash('The relationship could not be saved. Please, try again.'); } 
    } 

  }

here is my approve function

if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Relationship->create(); 
        $this->Relationship->save($this->request->data);
        $this->Session->setFlash('The information has been saved');}
        else{$this->Session->setFlash('The information couldnt be saved');}
```

im assuming I've missed some simple code, any help would be appreciated
its inserted in a new column - not in the column relating to that users relationship*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post doesn't the problem at whole, but what I understand you should follow some steps described below:

- When first half of the info saved in `Relationship` table then you have to get the `id` of that entry and you can get like following:

  `$this->Relationship->save($this->request->data);`

  `$lastId = $this->Relationship->id; // will gives you id of first half info saved`
- Then  you have to embed that `$lastId` with the rest of the info i.e last half after request confirmation. If you can embed that ID to the second half info that is within `$this->request->data`, then `$this->Relationship->save($this->request->data)` will update the previous saved row. In that case, you don't need `$this->Relationship->create();`.

  According to cakePHP, if any data contains `id` within it, then instead of creating new row and save, it will update the corresponding row having that `id`.